# Can somebody explain why a parametric to cartesian conversion of a perturbed parabola produces this strange situation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

A downward opening parabola described by $x=2at$ and $y=-a t^2$ is perturbed by adding a small quantity, proportional to the y-coordinate, in the expression for $x$. The perturbed curve is $x=2at+at^2\delta$ and $y=-a t^2$. $0<\delta<=1$. When plotted with values $a=1$ and $\delta=0.1$, produces a perturbed parabola with its vertex close to the unperturbed parabola. See figure 1 (Blue, unperturbed. Orange, perturbed).
[image: Using Parametric coordinates]

When converted to Cartesian coordinates, using the standard technique, a conic equation $x^2+2xy\delta +y^2+4ay=0$ is obtained (the curve is a rotated parabola). The vertex of this parabola is at $(\frac{-a}{\delta},\frac{-a}{\delta^2})$. To verify, when solved for and graphed, with previous values for $a$ and$\delta$, $y=\frac{-2a-x\delta\pm2\sqrt{a^2+ax\delta}}{\delta^2}$, a parabola with its vertex in the third quadrant is obtained as expected from the calculated vertex position for the Cartesian transformed curve. See figure 2 (Blue, unperturbed. Orange, perturbed).
[image: Using Cartesian coordinates]

Why the vertex is shifting after the coordinate transformation? Can somebody please explain where I may be committing a mistake.

Comment: The vertex is not shifting, what looks like "the vertex" of the orange curve on the first plot is not actually the vertex. The vertex is elsewhere, as you yourself computed. The scales on your plots are very different. Any point on a parabola, or any smooth convex curve, will look like "the vertex" if you make the tangent line at it horizontal and zoom in closely enough (by Taylor's expansion). The orange curve is only close to the blue curve near the origin.

Comment: Yes, vertex shifts if you make a non-isometric change of coordinates of a non-axis aligned parabola, that's normal.

Comment: Reply to comment by Conifold: I am not sure I understand your argument.  As far as I know, a parabola has only one vertex and that is where the two 'branches' come together. In both figures the vertices are clearly discernible.

Comment: Reply to comment by intelligenti pauca: The original parabola given by the parametric equations is sheared by $\delta$.  The parametric equations of the sheared parabola plots as expected (figure 1).  No further non-isometric translation is performed when parametric to cartesian conversion is performed (which produces the strange result).  Can you please explain your argument in detail?